# How do I change the absolute path in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

Echo `__DIR__` command; Returns `C:\Server\domains\joomla\` similar to the path that Windows Explorer shows. How and what to change in the Apache settings so that the `__DIR__` command returns the path `__SERVER\domains\joomla\` So that hosted projects and sites in the `\domains` folder do not have to be reconfigured when transferring to another computer. To define the path in projects in the same way as in Windows: `%APPDATA%/`, `%PROGRAMFILES%/`. For the `__DIR__` command to return `%__SERVER%/` or `__SERVER/`. Very often we need to transfer projects from one disk to another disk in the Apache server, just as often we need to transfer several dozen projects from a PC to another user's PC. I want to automate the entire process so that projects DON't need to change the absolute paths of sites in configs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: so try to make your question more clear.